# Selenium: WebDriver - System.TypeLoadException unhandled every time I run the most basic project

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, typeloadexception

Error details:

> System.TypeLoadException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233054
>    Message=Could not load type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver' from assembly
>  >'WebDriver, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>    Source=WebDriver
>    TypeName=OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver
>    StackTrace:
>         at Driver.Main(String[] args)
>         at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>         at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence 
> assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>         at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>         at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext 
> >executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, 
> >ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, 
> >ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>         at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>    InnerException:

I am running Visual C# 2010 on Windows 8. I changed the target framework to .Net framework 4 (from .Net framework 4 Client Profile). I tried the big three browsers:

```
    //IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Same error every time (basically, anyway). The code comes straight out of their docs:
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Just starting out with Selenium, hoping to automate a few simple tasks to start out. If I figure it out before I get an answer, I'll post it as an update.

Edit: tried to clean up formatting a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurred because I tried to compile a new Selenium based project before I added the references. After I realized the mistake I added references to all the assemblies, and still got the error. Turns out Visual Studio was "stuck" as I am now aware is not uncommon. A quick restart of the IDE was all that was necessary.